# How to resume cfn-init commands after reboot in linux - redhat 7.4?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to resume cfn-init in Redhat linux after reboot?

I have cfn-hup and cfn-auto-reloader setup correctly. And I have 'reboot' as one of the commands. All the commands run perfectly till this reboot command. And after the machine comes back from reboot it does not resume the rest of the cfn-init commands. In windows there's 'WaitAfterCompletion' option. Is there anything as such in linux? Just wondering if I'm missing something here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Overall, in linux, you shouldn't have to reboot within a script unless it is something like a kernel update. That being said,
Don't think cfn-init has a direct way to resume operation after reboot in linux, but you can use this linux workaround (using a file to resume script) and call it in your user-data to resume your remaining portion of cfn-init post reboot.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145294/how-to-continue-a-script-after-it-reboots-the-machine

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle linux reboot with user-data, this is an example with amazon linux 2 but it should work with redhat as well.

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
    #!/bin/bash -xe
    exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
    # update the system
    yum update -y
    # Check if kernel update requires a reboot, if yes it does reboot
    needs-restarting -r || 
    {
      # reset user data so it processes again after reboot
      rm -f /var/lib/cloud/instances/*/sem/config_scripts_user
      echo rebooting ... $(date)
      reboot
      exit
    }
    # commands that run after reboot ...
```